# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'compid'

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently building a custom CRM and have run into an issue.

The tables in question are the `contacts & company` table. The contact form is what I'm currently working on where staff can add new customers and assign them to a company. The company ID (`compid`) is a foreign key that links the contacts table to the companies table. The odd thing is, its pulling the data from the companies table but wont submit the form as it's giving me an incorrect integer value. However in the value box, i have echoed the ID of the company.

Please can someone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

```
<th class="text-nowrap" scope="row">Company Name</th>
<td><div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($compid_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
<select type="text" name="compid" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $compid; ?>">
    <option hidden>Select Company</option>
    <?php
        $get_comp_list_SQL = "SELECT * FROM `companies` ORDER BY `compname` ASC";
         $result_get_comp_list = mysqli_query($con,$get_comp_list_SQL);
         // while loop
         while ($row_get_comp_list = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_comp_list)) 
         {
             $comp_list_ID = $row_comp_list['id'];
             $comp_list_name = $row_get_comp_list['compname']; 
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $comp_list_ID; ?>"><?php echo $comp_list_name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is the column `id` or `compid`?

Answer (score 0):

comp id was the column. I could't see the wood through the trees last night. The issue was:

```
$comp_list_name = $row_get_comp_list['compname'];
```

It should have been:

```
$comp_get_list_name = $row_get_comp_list['compname'];
```

It was missing a "get" in the comp_list_name